# Set touchable area of SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Is there a property of `SKSpriteNode` that lets you manually set its touchable area?

I have a sprite textured with a PNG, it only seems to detect touches on the opaque portion of the PNG. So a small circle inside a large blank canvas actually has a tiny touchable area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an SKNode that is the size you would like the touchable area to be.  Add your textured sprite as a child of the new SKNode.  Check to see if the new SKNode was touched instead of if the textured sprite was touched.

Comment: I'm having trouble setting the frame size of the SKNode - the sprite inside it disappears when I modify that property. But this seems like the right way to go.

Comment: Set the size of the SKNode and its other properties before adding the textured spriteNode

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"childName"]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"You touched to child of sprite");
    }
}
-(void)sprite
{
    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"spriteImageName"];
    [self addChild:sprite];

    SKSpriteNode *spriteChild = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"childImageName"];
    spriteChild.name = @"childName"; 
    [sprite addChild:spriteChild];
}
```